# Why PL/SQL developer mark reusable as keyword in oracle

Tags: oracle, keyword, plsqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle 12.1 with PL/SQL developer and I notice that `reusable` is reserved keyword.

I can't find any documentation of `reusable`  keyword in oracle, and not exists in [Oracle/PL/SQL's Reserved Words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a42525/apb.htm)

I found [REUSE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/clauses004.htm) keyword regarding file management

> Specify REUSE to allow Oracle to reuse an existing file. You must specify REUSE if you specify a filename that already exists.

I don't find it also in PL/SQL Developer 11.0
User’s Guide

I **can** use this "keyword" to create table

```
create table reusable(reusable varchar2(1))
```

So why `reusable` is marked as keyword and by who?

[image]

It doesn't happens in Oracle SQL Developer

**EDIT**

I found only [Serially Reusable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_packages.htm#g1042474)

> A package that is marked `SERIALLY_REUSABLE`

Comment: It works fine for me in 11.2, 12.2 and 18c. I don't have 12.1 so can't be sure if it's specific to that version.

Comment: @KaushikNayak reusable isn't marked as keyword in your  PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: I'm not sure how a keyword is related to PL/SQL Developer, which is a third party tool. I tried in SQL developer and also dbfiddle  & it works in the versions I mentioned.

Comment: @KaushikNayak in plsql developer you can set some styles for code. but why specific words are shown as keywords that question can only be answerd by the developer of that Software. I think that the question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Ok.. I realise now after the edits that I hadn't read it accurately,  that you **can** create a table. I thought you couldn't and was trying to see if it's a database problem.

Comment: Maybe a good question for the allround automations support forum. http://forums.allroundautomations.com/list.html

Comment: @Rene I try to register and didn't get email confirmation for hours, can you ask there?

Comment: Your link to reserved words is pointing to a very old version.  
 See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/reservedwords.htm#LNPLS019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround:

Remove `REUSABLE` line from default.kwf in the PL/SQL Developer installation directory.